# how to convert png animation to gif and keep the transparent using ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, png, gif

I would like to convert png animation file to gif in windows, 
I choose to use ffmpeg, as I have many of pngs to covert, cmd is quite straight forward in this case.

the sample img here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTkdc.png

tried:

`ffmpeg -i SPGGMEb.png -vocdec gif output.gif`

everything seems fine but the transparent background turns to black, as:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CbO8.gif

how can I keep the transparent background during conversion?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952389/12373956

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get better transparency with GIFs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952376/how-to-get-better-transparency-with-gifs)